# How to add our own emoji in softkeyboard

Tags: android-softkeyboard, emoji, android-input-method

I am trying to figure out how the emoji (emoticon) selections are implemented on the Facebook app and the Google Hangouts app.

I have creating a softkeyboard like emoji. But then i think how apps like facebook,skype etc react on it. A lot of emoji keyboard Apps are using unicode to send their image and these codes are universal.

**I am thinking that this type of keyboard can only be useful within this app and not with other apps or Operating Systems.**

This keyboard is not using Unicode sequences but rather just local image assets.

**My Question is**

If i add my own **emoji from local db** and if i don't use UniCode and send it by creating a spannable ImageSpan. These Images can be sent to what's App ,Facebook and skype or not.

Because I am creating new Emoji images. Is this work .

```
Just need suggestion or

Does anyone have an idea of how this can be implemented.
```

**Or is it possible to convert my Emoji Icons to UNi Code**

Answer (score 2):

see this [link](https://github.com/ankushsachdeva/emojicon)

**Softkeyboard.java**

```
    if (primaryCode == 32) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
        popupWindow = new EmojiconsPopup(popupView, this);
        // final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow();
        popupWindow.setSizeForSoftKeyboard();
        popupWindow.setSize(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        popupWindow.showAtLocation(mInputView.getRootView(), Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);

        // Bring soft keyboard up : NOT WORKING
        final InputMethodManager mInputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getBaseContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

        mInputMethodManager.showSoftInput(popupView, 0);


        // If the text keyboard closes, also dismiss the emoji popup
        popupWindow.setOnSoftKeyboardOpenCloseListener(new OnSoftKeyboardOpenCloseListener() {

            @Override
            public void onKeyboardOpen(int keyBoardHeight) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onKeyboardClose() {
                if (popupWindow.isShowing())
                    popupWindow.dismiss();
            }
        });

        popupWindow.setOnEmojiconClickedListener(new OnEmojiconClickedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onEmojiconClicked(Emojicon emojicon) {
                mComposing.append(emojicon.getEmoji());
                commitTyped(getCurrentInputConnection());

                customToast("" + emojicon.getEmoji());
            }
        });

        popupWindow.setOnEmojiconBackspaceClickedListener(new OnEmojiconBackspaceClickedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onEmojiconBackspaceClicked(View v) {
                KeyEvent event = new KeyEvent(0, 0, 0, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL, 0, 0, 0, 0, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENDCALL);
                customToast(" " + event);
                handleBackspace();
            }
        });
```

Some help for you..